# Javascript setTimeout for an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The concept is to create a lift operation. Upon clicking 1, the display should show 1 and similarly for other floors.
I have done the code.

if i click on 2, 3 ,4 consecutively 2nd floor is having a delay of 10000ms which is set in setTimeOut but 3&4 are executing immediately.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/j9agmxwx/)

Could someone help me out to get equal intervals on 4 floors.

```
var liftArray = [];
var liftCurrentPosition = 1;

    $(document).ready(function(){


    $("#currentPosHTML").text(liftCurrentPosition);

});
$(".floorbuttons").click(function(){

    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    var selectedfloor = parseInt($(this).text());
    console.log(selectedfloor);

    if(liftArray == 0 || selectedfloor!=liftArray[liftArray.length-1]){
    liftArray.push(selectedfloor);

    setInterval(function(){ 
    movelift(liftArray[0]);
    liftArray.splice(0,1);
    },10000);   
    }
});

function movelift(value){
    $("#currentPosHTML").text(value);
    liftCurrentPosition = value;
    $(".floorbuttons").each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == liftCurrentPosition){
    $(this).attr("disabled",false);
    }
    });
};
```

Comment: It looks like in this case better to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, if you not expect call `movelift(liftArray[0]);` multiple time with `undefined` value.

Comment: setTimeOut also didnt help.

Comment: Let me know the reason why was my question downvoted?

Comment: Also as I understood you expectation is switching floors just every 10 seconds, but each click on button will create new closure that executed after 10 sec, but differense in time between clicks will be the same as you did by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setTimeout` method inside the `movelift` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setInterval` is correct, but you have to make sure you only start it if the elevator is currently not working. If it's working, it will trigger every 5 seconds, and when it has reached all floors, the interval needs to be cancelled.

So add this as a general variable:

```
var refreshIntervalId;
```

Change the click function to:

```
$(".floorbuttons").click(function(){

    $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    var selectedfloor = parseInt($(this).text());
    console.log(selectedfloor);
    if (liftArray == 0) {
        refreshIntervalId =  setInterval(function () {
            movelift();
        }, 10000);
    }

    if(liftArray == 0 || selectedfloor!=liftArray[liftArray.length-1]){
        liftArray.push(selectedfloor);
    }
});
```

And lastly change the `movelift` function:

```
function movelift(){

    var value = liftArray.shift();
    if (!value) {
        clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        return;
    }

    $("#currentPosHTML").text(value);
    liftCurrentPosition = value;
    $(".floorbuttons").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == liftCurrentPosition){
            $(this).attr("disabled",false);
        }
    });  
 };
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9agmxwx/2/)